# Traversing Hash Map linear using generics (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, data-structures, hash

I have a hash map which uses linear probing to deal with collisions. I would like to traverse it. Conceptually, this is quite easy, however, the use of generics is spinning me off.

The entries in the internal array of the hash map have their key-value pairs as generics - like this

```
public entry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
```

These entries are stored in an entry array - like this

```
    private entry[] entries;
```

I would like to traverse the hash map beginning at a certain key, I will reach the end of the internal array, then go back to the beginning of the array up to the key, in a circular fashion so the whole array is covered.

```
public V traverse(K k) {

    //look from current key
    for(int i = (int)k; i < entries.length; i++){
        //visit node
    }
    //go back to start, and look up to key
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)k; i++){
        //visit node
    }
}
```

I've realized that type casting the key as an integer was sort of stupid, but i'm struggling to find a working way to actually do this traversal.

Comment: Well, you first have to find it... Loop over `entries` until you find the one with `.key == k` and then use your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you maybe you can create LinkedHashMap(HashMap)() and with it you can do it transversally.

Answer (score 0):

A HashMap does not store the entries in the order you expect. The ordering is based on the hash of the key, and organized as an array of linked-lists.

If you want to have a defined ordering you should use TreeMap, which uses the natural ordering of the key. If you need a custom sorting you can provide a Comparator by constructor. Then just iterate on the map.keySet.

But I think what you need (starting the iteration somewhere in the middle) is not supported. You start iterating at the first node, and do nothing until you reach your desired key, then do your work with the rest of the entries, then start again iterating until you reach your desired key again.